# Prevent Parse client from retrieving full user list

Tags: parse-platform

For security reasons, I'd like to prevent my Parse client app (iOS) from being able to fetch the list of Parse users. Currently, anyone with the application id and client key (which are trivial to hack out of the app) can fetch the entire user list by running this request:

```
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/_User
```

Comment: You can security in the class to prevent public reading, that it will be accessible only with some specific role you create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid User table being searched publicly, disable `Find` permission in your class security settings (CLPs). Make sure to checkout Advanced security tab to see all permissions instead of only Read/Write